# extracting php array with search

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array , like this

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [did] => 1 [title] => first link [link] => link.com ) 
Array ( [did] => 1 [title] => second link [link] => link2.com ) 
Array ( [id] => 2 [did] => 2 [title] => forum 1 [link] => forum.php ) 
Array ( [did] => 2 [title] => forum 2 => viewtopic.php ) 
Array ( [did] => 2 [title] => register [link] => register.php )
```

and i want to extract it , like this

```
- first link
-- seconde link
- forum 1
-- forum 2
-- register
```

id , is main , and did , is parent in this array.
any way?
i want this output :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link.com">first link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link2.com">seconde link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="forum.php"> forum 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="viewtopic.php"> forum 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php"> register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you have this array's or you can change them?

Comment: What have you tried? Start by using a `foreach` loop and conditions to check child-parent relation.

Comment: How this data added to array?? What you need to do?? Is there any frame works? or peo PHP???

Comment: this array used for menu & submenu.
foreach loop , does'nt work for me , perhaps , i did it wrong.

Comment: ok but i ask to you if you can change the arrays or where you get this arrays?

Comment: Incude the code that you have tried.

Comment: @daremachine , i can change it.

Comment: @jaxneil better change structure with children like array(array(id = 1, title=>'first', children=> array(array(id=>3, title=>'sub'), array(id=>4, title=>'sub2')))); you can iterate recursion on children if any exist and make new sub category under parent

Comment: this is what can help to you http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/build-menu-with-recursive-functions/

Comment: @jaxneil np. I think this is better and more maintainable approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure isn't that clean, but sometime the data doesn't come in clean.  Something like this should work (although the `<?=` short tag may cause issues if that isn't set up in your environment).  I used colons instead of braces only because I think it is easier to read in this kind of mixed code.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($arr as $item): ?>
    <li><a href="<?=$item['link']?>"><?=$item['title']?></a>
        <ul>
        <?php 
            foreach ($arr as $item2): 
               if ((array_key_exists('did', $item2) && ($item2['did'] == $item['id'])):
        ?>
             <li><a href="<?=$item2['link']?>"><?=$item2['title']?></a></li>    
        <?php
               endif;
             endforech;
        ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```